# bootstrap datatable sort column based on another column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, datatable, datatables

I have a column which is calculated based on another date column to show in a years/months/days format. I also want this column to be sorted as the date column but since it's a string it is sorting differently.

[image]

Here is my code to for datatable config.

```js
            "columnDefs": [{  // set default column settings
                'orderable': false,
                'targets': [1, 9]
            }, {
                "searchable": false,
                "targets": [1, 9]
            }],
            "order": [
                [5, "asc"]
            ] // set first column as a default sort by asc
```

Is there any way I can attach the sort for column 6 "At Work" to column 5?

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok found the answer to the question.

Datatable provide a way to sort orthogonal data by letting you add data-order which will determine the sort order rather then the value contained by the table cell.

Below is the example (from dataTable documentation) which suggests how to do it :)

```html
<tr>
    <td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td data-order="1303682400">Mon 25th Apr 11</td>
    <td data-order="3120">$3,120/m</td>
</tr>
```

So in my case I have to add timestamp to table cell using data-order to sort it correctly.

Comment: Thank you! It's hard to find what you are looking for in their documentation

Comment: God damnit, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Perfect! Nice! You saved me!

Comment: I didn't know about this way to sort one column from different data. I always used to hide one column then fix the js code with targets. This way is far more easy to understand!